# Exporting text sequences with labels from Inception Annotation engine

Tags: nlp, annotations

I am using INCEpTION (https://inception-project.github.io/) to annotate my legal documents. Instead of any of the export formats provided in Inception, is there a way I could export the raw text sequences I labelled, along with their label names?

The use case I have here is in creating a dataset where I annotate the sentences in my text as text sequences (sentence boundary detection is not well-solved for the legal domain), along with a custom tag for each sentence.

An ideal export format would be, on each line of a txt file:
text  label

The data format I am hoping to achieve is similar to what you see here: https://github.com/Law-AI/semantic-segmentation/blob/master/data/text/1953_L_1.txt

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have configured a span layer called `Segment` in INCEpTION (which translates to the internal name `webanno.custom.Segment`) and that you have annotated several sentences of a document called `my-text.txt` as `Segment` on the Annotation page in INCEpTION. Lets further assume that the `Segment` layer is configured to have a String feature called `label` where you put values such as `Facts`, `Ratio of the decision`, and `Precedent`.

Now, you can export a single annotated document via the **Export** button in the action bar of the Annotation page in the **UIMA CAS XMI (XML 1.0)**. What you get is a ZIP file containing two files inside:

- an `my-text.xmi` file containing the annotated text
- a `TypeSystem.xml` file containing the annotation scheme

Assuming you have Python 3 installed, you can now install [DKPro Cassis](https://pypi.org/project/dkpro-cassis/), a library which helps you make use of the two files above.

```
pip install dkpro-cassis
```

Now, you can write a short Python script using Cassis which reads the annotations and outputs them in the format you desire:

```
from cassis import *

with open('TypeSystem.xml', 'rb') as f:
  typesystem = load_typesystem(f)

with open('my-text.xmi', 'rb') as f:
  doc = load_cas_from_xmi(f, typesystem=typesystem)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
  for segment in doc.select('webanno.custom.Segment'):
    f.write(f"{segment.get_covered_text()}\t{segment.label}\n")
```

There is a similar ready-to-run example available on the [Python examples](https://inception-project.github.io/example-projects/python/) section of the INCEpTION website.

*Disclaimer: I am working on the INCEpTION project.*